# JSXGraph performance issue

Tags: javascript, performance, plot, jsxgraph

I am currently experimenting a bit with function plotting using JSXGraph and experienced some performance issues.

Even when the website is on IDLE it seems to spend a lot of time in the removeToInsertLater function called by the update function of JSXGraph.

I tried to work a bit with the suspendUpdate() method of the board without success.

So i wondered if i maybe doing something wrong or its just the normal behavior of JSXGraph?

I also would like to know, if i cant do anything against this, what are some good alternatives to plot mathematical functions.

Edit:
Here a small example
http://jsbin.com/vodokevude/1/edit?html,output

Especially under firefox it seems to be extremly slow, doing some pan and zoom actions freezes my browser for several seconds.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example? If you are plotting static function graphs, supplying the attribute "needsRegularUpdate:false" will prevent the function plot to be recomputed in every update. 
Further, you can experiment with initBoard("dviid", {minimizeReflow: value, ...}): Possible values are 'svg', 'all' and 'none', where 'svg' is the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above example the horizontal axis ranges from -2 to 2500 and the board settings contain `grid:true`. With this attribute a grid for every integer position is drawn. Therefore, there the canvas has about 2500 vertical lines. That is the reason while the construction slows down the browser - and makes the background grey. The solution is:

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {
   boundingbox: [-2, 10, 10, -2],
   axis: true,
   grid: false, ...
```